How can I tell what deleted an S3 object?
I'm looking at my CloudTrail logs pertaining to the deletion of an object from an S3 bucket. I can see this (lightly censored):
{type=AssumedRole, principalid=AROAxxx:xxx, arn=arn:aws:sts::xxx:assumed-role/OrganizationAccountAccessRole/xxx, accountid=xxx, invokedby=null, accesskeyid=ASIAxxx, username=null, sessioncontext={attributes={mfaauthenticated=false, creationdate=2024-xx-xxTxx:xx:xxZ}, sessionissuer={type=Role, principalid=AROAXxxx, arn=arn:aws:iam::xxx:role/OrganizationAccountAccessRole, accountid=xxx, username=OrganizationAccountAccessRole}, ec2roledelivery=null, webidfederationdata=null}}
Is there a way to get more information about how the object was deleted? In particular which user deleted it?

See Monitor actions taken with assumed roles.

The information that you are looking for will be a part of AWS CloudTrail - Data events.
s3:DeleteObject action qualifies for AWS CloudTrail - Data events. Therefore unless the AWS CloudTrail is configured to capture Data events it will not show up in AWS CloudTrail - Event History.
Do you have AWS CloudTrail - Data events configured?
